# using node.js check the returned value is comma separated

Tags: jquery, node.js

My data sometimes returns value like 'FF' or `PP` or something like that.
Sometimes data returns combination of `FF,GG,HH,PP` i.e. comma separated values.

How can I detect the returned value is comma separated or single string?

Comment: Please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Also make sure you've read [**how-to-ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery and node.js

Comment: Maybe it is a buffer. Try applying `.toString()` to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your content never contains a comma unless as a seperater the easiest way will be to use the split function that is available on a string object.

for example say your input is:

```
var input = "FF";
var parsedOutput = input.split(",");
```

parsedOutput will be an array with one item, "FF"

if you however received an input such as

```
var input = "FF,GG,HH,PP"
var parsedOutput = input.split(",");
```

you will receive an array with four items in like so:

```
["FF", "GG", "HH", "PP"]
```

if you only want to detect which format it is in you can do it even easier via the indexOf method of the string object and if it is !=-1 then it does include a comma e.g.

```
if(input.indexOf(",") !=-1){
    //then it is a comma seperated value
} else {
    //it is not
}
```